# show records from sql created during specific week

Tags: php, sql

I have tons of records that are in my database table `leadactivity` basically I need to display all the records that were created in the first week of the current month, then also another query to display records in the second week, same for third week and then finally the fourth week of the current month.

I have a column called `created_date` which onupdate puts in the current timestamp

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. And show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use date functions for this:

```
select la.*
from leadactivity la
where day(la.created_date) between 1 and 7 and
      created_date >= curdate() + (1 - day(curdate())) day;
```

The above assumes MySQL syntax.  Most databases have similar functionality, although the specific functions may differ.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'day' at line 4